# About Multi-level Page Tables

Tags: memory-management, operating-system, paging, cpu-architecture

I do not know how to calculate, Who can teach me how to calculate or demonstrate to me?
Thanks.

Assume one process needs one page table, for a 32-bit system with 4KB each page, if each table entry is 8 bytes and the average number of processes running in the system is 100, what’s the average storage space needed for storing all tables in this system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `4GB Physical memory` you have `4GB/4KB = 1MB` `2^20` `frames`.
Each process has its own `page-table` which will contain `2^20 entries`.
Each entry is of `8 byte` size.

`2^20*8 B` for process
`2^20*8*100 B` for the 100 processes.

That is `800MB` overhead.